# javascript - can't find a solution to create inner table inside rows

Tags: javascript, datatables

What javascript code must I write to have inner rows like this? I try to make this:

[image: row]

This is my JSfiddle example: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1fvy0e6r/)
I try follow different answers from stackoverflow but unsuccessfully.
Thanks for any hel`p`

Comment: Here is the [documentation on how to set up child rows](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Comment: I can't integrate datatables solution. Seems not working. Can you help me to fix? Please gilly, I try many times but is difficult for me

Comment: I just want use like a spoiler. Datatables solution don't permit to search inside row child if you using default searching and then is keeping default table layout style like in my picture above?

Comment: this is [row grouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html). In datatable 1.9 it was working through a third party extension , since datatable 1.10 you can not achieve through [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html) example.